# Combinatorics Can Someone Check over?

Tags: combinatorics

In a math class of $30$ students, $12$ out of $15$ girls are freshmen and $11$ out of $15$ boys are freshmen. What is the probability that in a randomly selected group of five students from the class, there will be two freshmen girls and three freshmen boys? Express your answer as a decimal to the nearest thousandth.

Can someone help check my answer?

Number of ways to select $2$ freshman girls: ${12 \choose 2}$

Number of ways to select $3$ freshman boys: ${11 \choose 3}$

using the formula: $n!/k!~(n-k)!$

${12 \choose 2}$ is $12! / (2!~10!)$, which is $66$.

${11 \choose 3}$ is $11! / (3!~8!)$, which is $165$

Number of ways to pick five students without restriction: ${30 \choose 5}$

${30 \choose 5}$ is $30! / (5!~25!)$, which is $142506$

$ \displaystyle \frac {66 \cdot 165}{142506} = \frac {605}{7917}$.

I entered the fraction into the system and it said it was wrong. Can someone check over again, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe because " Express your answer as a decimal to the nearest thousandth." (not fraction) ..The working seems fine to me

Comment: Please use mathjax to write your math

Comment: For a more general formulation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution